# How to Discover Core Router Brand

Tags: networking, router

Is there a way to check/discover what brand(cisco/juniper) is a core router in the internet? (in other words is outside my LAN)

I am looking for an alternative NMAP (or the the naming convention).

Comment: How is this relevant for you?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is it depends....

Long answer is it will depend on your service provider or manager of the device you are trying to gather information on. Also it will depend on how they expect you to interact with the device. If you are a simple end of the line consumer then as Keller mentioned most ISPs will limit the amount of identifying information available to an end user, leaving only fingerprinting as a valid way to determine the device type (nmap).

Also ISPs have been known to put useful information in the reverse dns entries of the ip address hops of you connections. Often you can gather not only device manufacture, but model number and which interface you traffic is traversing (Time Warner used to do this, haven't checked to see if they still are).

Where as if you have a legitimate need for the information, then the answer is just ask them, most ISP will gladly share the information if you are up front and honest with the reasons why you need that information. For example if you are peering with that ISP or have noticed "interesting" behavior when your traffic crosses their device. They would like to hear about it.

Now if you are asking how to technically finger print a device across the internet that you have no direct interaction with, then that is a post for a security group and they can explain tcp fingerprinting and all the gory details.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am aware of the naming conventions, and relying on them when available. Also aware of the fingerprinting techniques, as used by NMAP.
I just wanted to make sure there was no other route, that is easier and maybe more accurate. (asking the ISPs is not so easy if you are not peering or a client)

Answer (score 1):

Options

- Get a job with the ISP
- Call them and ask
- Search the Internet for articles with the ISP and "Cisco" or "Juniper" and make an educated guess

Most SP/Enterprise-level gear is designed to keep you from discovering this easily.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked it here unless I had done a thorough research on it. Thanks for the "creative answers".

Comment: My point was -- if you're an end-user trying to determine this information from your ISPs network, and you have a legitimate need for the info, you should be able to get the info from them.  If you're just curious (or have other intentions), nmap (and the method it employs) is your option.